# Save SSIS package(.dtsx) in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, runtime

All,

As I understand the code behind of SSIS is just an XML file. Is there any way so that I can load this whole XML in my SQL Server table and on runtime able to create a package on any given server using this XML file.

SO basically it is as simple as storing XMl file or blob data into SQL Server table and load it back on file system to create an actual SSIS package out of this XML.

TIA

Comment: Why would you want to?   Is there a problem you are trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. I haven't tried but I don't see any reason why it won't work.

Just note that which ever system you are trying to extract and run the package you would need to have SSIS engine installed on that system.

However I would like to advice that there is a more elegant way of dynamic SSIS package creation available. Here is the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135946.aspx

Comment: Kind of the restriction you say with .net we usually not have it on servers expect SSIS. So basically using any other kind of utility so I can create\convert or translate XML file into physical .dtsx file.

Comment: I really doubt that approach would work. Although SSIS is plain XML on the back, how are you going to take care of the configurations/logging/dynamic properties? Even if you store it on the table, you would still need to call the dtexec.exe program to start the package execution. Unless you have some very fancy program written to extract the string from the table and pass it onto the dtexec, I dont see a way how you could do this.